# Updating dependency package in Ubuntu through puppet?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I am updating the package like the below code?

> ```
> package { '<packageName1>':
>          ensure => latest,
> }
> ```

but it does not installing dependency package.

so I included the

> exec {'testing': command => "apt-get build-dep packageName1'}

But still not working ..how to implement installing dependency package.
Any other good ways??

Just now i tried with apt class.It also not working.

include apt

```
apt::builddep { 'packagename': }
```

Comment: You certainly don't want to be using Exec for this. Any chance we could see the output of running your manifest?

Comment: No not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a package section from one of our puppet manifests.  This is used on Ubuntu.

```
package { ["mysql-server", "libapache2-mod-auth-mysql", "php5-mysql"] :
        ensure  => present,
    }
```

`apt-get install puppet` sets everything up so that the "package" resource type knows how to install packages

example2
I have a vm without mysql-server installed
apt-get -s install mysql-server ( simulation mode ) gives this output

```
$ apt-get -s install mysql-server
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-2.6.32-38 linux-headers-2.6.32-38-server
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libnet-daemon-perl
  libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-server-5.1
  mysql-server-core-5.1
Suggested packages:
  dbishell libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libnet-daemon-perl
  libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libnet-daemon-perl (0.43-1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Inst libplrpc-perl (0.2020-2 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Inst libdbi-perl (1.609-1build1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Inst libdbd-mysql-perl (4.012-1ubuntu1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Inst mysql-client-core-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Inst mysql-client-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Inst mysql-server-core-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Inst mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Inst libhtml-template-perl (2.9-1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Inst mysql-server (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Conf libnet-daemon-perl (0.43-1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Conf libplrpc-perl (0.2020-2 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Conf libdbi-perl (1.609-1build1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Conf libdbd-mysql-perl (4.012-1ubuntu1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Conf mysql-client-core-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Conf mysql-client-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Conf mysql-server-core-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Conf mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
Conf libhtml-template-perl (2.9-1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid)
Conf mysql-server (5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 Ubuntu:10.04/lucid-updates)
```

So I made manifest file like this

```
$ more p.pp
package { "mysql-server":
ensure => present
}
```

and ran it like this

```
$ sudo puppet apply p.pp
Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet1 in environment production in 0.12 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]//Package[mysql-server]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 57.49 seconds
```

After doing this, mysql-server and it's dependancies were all installed

Comment: It will add packages but dependent package it wont add.

Comment: @Python_Dude if you install it with `apt-get` yourself, does it install the dependent package?

Comment: All ``puppet apply`` does is run ``/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install mysql-server`` or similar.  You can check the exact command by using apply --verbose --debug and examining the output